# Method cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Tags: c#

I added .dll: `AxWMPLib` and using method `get_Ctlcontrols()` but it show error like:

> AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

This is my code using `get_Ctlcontrols()` method:

```
this.Media.get_Ctlcontrols().stop();
```

I don't know why this error appears. Can anyone explain me and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Thank you for this question Ian, it's very easily searchable through search engines and Paulo's answer is general enough that a lot of people searching for similar answers will be able to receive fast help. When using reflection, get_... forms are returned in output from typeof(path.to.MyClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access a property by calling explicitly its get method.

Try this (notice that `get_` and `()` are missing):

```
this.Media.Ctlcontrols.stop();
```

Here is a small example about how properties work in C# - just to make you understand, this does not pretend to be accurate, so please read something more serious than this :)

```
using System;

class Example {

    int somePropertyValue;

    // this is a property: these are actually two methods, but from your 
    // code you must access this like it was a variable
    public int SomeProperty {
        get { return somePropertyValue; }
        set { somePropertyValue = value; }
    }
}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();

        // you access properties like this:
        e.SomeProperty = 3; // this calls the set method
        Console.WriteLine(e.SomeProperty); // this calls the get method

        // you cannot access properties by calling directly the 
        // generated get_ and set_ methods like you were doing:
        e.set_SomeProperty(3);
        Console.WriteLine(e.get_SomeProperty());

    }

}
```