# Entity.Id.Set : cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I get this error when try to set Id of Entity.

```
    Entity val = new Entity(createdEntity.LogicalName);
    val.set_Id(createdEntity.Id);
```

How ever I could solve the get method errors, by changing :

```
 get_Value()
```

to

```
Value
```

By omitting `get and ()`.
ex :

```
val.get_Value();
```

changed to :

```
   val.Value;
```

But How can I set Id for single entity?
I mean how can I solve the line :

```
val.set_Id(createdEntity.Id);
```

Or set Item just like this line :

```
val.get_Attributes().set_Item(item.Key, attributes.get_Item(item.Key));
```

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method cannot explicitly call operator or accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500315/method-cannot-explicitly-call-operator-or-accessor)

Comment: you are working on a decompiled code, correct?

Comment: @GuidoPreite : Yes, IT is decompiled Code.
How can I solve this?
Or in Constructors I get 
 "Constructor can not call  itself".

How Can I solve the set methods?
I could solve the get by Omitting get_ and ().

Comment: @GuidoPreite : How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that syntax when you decompile the assembly/executable you didn't load the CRM SDK DLLs inside your decompiler.

Check with your decompiler software how to load the referenced assemblies (if you are using ILSpy for example you just need to open them first), after when you decompile again the file it will show the right syntax.

Comment: I just decompiled the necessary before de-compiling my target .dll.
Why I did not pay attention to your reply at first time? !!! 
Thank you bro !!

Answer (score 1):

Like explained in [this community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/296981), rewrite your classes/methods using native `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query` namespace.